# Combinatorics: combinations with exclusions

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Given a following sample set of N = 8:

A F G

B H

C

D

E

How would one calculate a number of combinations with following rules (K is the Number of elements to choose from the set):

1. Elements in horizontal rows can NOT be combined, i.e for K=2, AF, AG, FG are not valid combinations.
2. Order is not important
3. Repetitions are not allowed

so for a given set of N=8, answers are:

for K=2 answer is 24

for K=3 answer is 34

for K=4 answer is 23

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! Since you are active in other parts of the Stack Exchange network, you know to make your questions clear. What is the meaning of $R$ in your question? Is it the number of elements in the combination?

Comment: Good spot, sorry added explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your answer is a problem (the number of combinations from $8$ with two restrictions) that can be done in this way:

Count the combinations of $K$ elements chosen without replacement from the $8$ possibilities;

Count how many of those combinations have $2$ through $K$ elements chosen from the first row;

Count how many of those combinations have $2$ through $K$ elements chosen from the second row;

Count how many of those combinations have both $2$ through $K$ elements chosen from the first row and $2$ through $K$ elements chosen from the second row;

Then use the [Inclusion–exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to find your answer.

Is that enough of a hint?